# Foreign Key invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add a foreign key to my table but i am getting this error,

> ERROR at line 3: ORA-00904: "DEDUCID": invalid identifier

```
ALTER TABLE pr_cust
ADD CONSTRAINT deduc_fk
FOREIGN KEY (deducid)
REFERENCES pr_deduc;
```

I have this other table named pr_deduc that has a column named deducid, that is a char with one value as my primary key. I have it spelled corrected, unless i am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `deducid` you mention has to be a column on `pr_cust`, and you are not referencing the column in the other table. The propper syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE pr_cust
ADD CONSTRAINT deduc_fk
FOREIGN KEY (deducid)
REFERENCES pr_deduc(deducid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE pr_cust
ADD CONSTRAINT deduc_fk
FOREIGN KEY (deducid)
REFERENCES pr_deduc(deducid);
```